# Z3 partial order doesn't seem to be reflexive

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I am trying to learn to use the [Z3](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) solver. In [this tutorial](https://z3prover.github.io/papers/programmingz3.html#sec-special-relations) it is explained that a partial order is best defined using the built-in `PartialOrder` function. It seems to me that the resulting order is not reflexive, as the following bit of code returns sat:

```
>>> s = Solver()
>>> R = PartialOrder(IntSort(), 0)
>>> x = Int('x')
>>> s.add(Not(R(x, x)))
>>> s.check()
sat
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

I checked the other properties (transitivity and antisymmetry) which seem to work as expected. Also, changing `PartialOrder(IntSort(), 0)` to `LinearOrder(IntSort(), 0)` changes the answer to unsat.

The model for the `Not(R(x, x))` formula doesn't make me any wiser:

```
 next = [else ->
         If(And(member(Var(0), Var(2)),
                Not(member(Var(1), Var(3)))),
            pair(cons(Var(1), fst(Var(4))),
                 cons(Var(1), snd(Var(4)))),
            Var(4))],
 partial-order = [else ->
                  Or(connected(cons(Var(0), nil),
                               Var(1),
                               cons(Var(0), nil)),
                     Var(0) == Var(1))],
 member = [else ->
           If(is(nil, Var(1)),
              False,
              If(head(Var(1)) == Var(0),
                 True,
                 member(Var(0), tail(Var(1)))))],
 connected = [else ->
              If(fst(pair(nil, Var(2))) == nil,
                 False,
                 If(member(Var(1), fst(pair(nil, Var(2)))),
                    True,
                    connected(fst(pair(nil, Var(2))),
                              Var(1),
                              snd(pair(nil, Var(2))))))]]
```

I'm using version 4.11.2.0.

Comment: Did this basically define a strict partial order (one that is asymmetric and transitive, but irreflexive instead of reflexive)?

Comment: I checked but `R(x, x)` is also satisfiable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z3's `PartialOrder` is supposed to be reflexive. So, indeed, there seems to be something fishy going on here. I seem to recall that these sorts of relations worked on uninterpreted-sorts better, or at least finite-domains; but even then I'm seeing bizarre behavior.

For instance, this code:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
A = DeclareSort('A')
R = PartialOrder(A, 0)
a = Const('a', A)
s.add(Not(R(a, a)))
print(s.check())
```

prints `sat`. But it's *supposed* to be equivalent (i.e., same semantics, but with better performance) to the following:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
A = DeclareSort('A')
R = Function('R', A, A, BoolSort())
x, y, z = Consts('x y z', A)
s.add(ForAll([x], R(x, x)))
s.add(ForAll([x,y], Implies(And(R(x, y), R(y, x)), x == y)))
s.add(ForAll([x,y,z], Implies(And(R(x, y), R(y, z)), R(x, z))))

a = Const('a', A)
s.add(Not(R(a, a)))
print(s.check())
```

which prints `unsat` as you'd expect.

I'd recommend filing a ticket at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues and see what the developers have to say. Please do update this question back with what you find out!

Comment: Thanks, I've opened a ticket [here](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/6646).

Comment: @wijnanduu Looks like this was a genuine bug, and it's now fixed: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/ce501e0b6e6bab4c2d88f6eff434561f172920bf